# upload migrate tool instead of composer - possible?

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

While trying to migrate, I have some complaints about magento not having source / destination documents mapped; however, they are in map.xml (default there, no need to tweak).

I'm using the correct migration tool (2.2.5) from 1.6.2.

```
←[0;31m[2018-07-10 00:52:26][ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped:core_store,core_store_group,core_website
←[0m←[0;31m[2018-07-10 00:52:26][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: store ,store_group,store_website
←[0m←[0;34m[NOTICE]: You can use --auto or -a option to ignore not mapped differences between source and destination to continue migration
```

I have double checked source database and the tables are in the old magento database.

Any ideas?

Comment: I renamed my map.xml file and magento didn't complained about not finding it, but gave me the exact same error.

Comment: My bad, as per https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/375 I had to modify map-stores.xml.dist not map.xml